# How effective are banners in the left sidebar on ecommerce websites?

Tags: usability, e-commerce, case-studies

Does anyone have a case or study about the effectiveness of the banner that appears after the sidebar menu?

A client insists on using them but this banner represents less than 1% of clicks.

[image: banner before the sidebar menu]

Comment: There might be a low number of clicks, but have they seen any uplift in sales for products featured in the banner due to the additional exposure? In my experience, those banners are valuable more for impressions than clicks. Since every product featured in them is visible on every pdp on the site

Comment: the question you should make him is: is this banner needed for a sales flow process? or will it interfere in the sale? For example, for what I see in your screen capture, I can see a product listing which I presume (don't know) will lead to a sale. While it's not clear and could be just a catalog, let's assume it will lead to a sale. That banner will interfere in the flow and should be taken off for good. However, if it's a catalog and the real sale is in the banner, then yes, you should consider an additional ad piece (although not exactly there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Google's Adsense heatmap. You're right, the lower left is comparatively less hot to place ads or promotions or banners than say top left or center.

In your case, you don't want to place the banners on top right because it is annoying and will be in the way of accessing the main functionality.

Hence, the benefits of moving it to the bottom left are

> 1. Less annoying
> 2. Not in the way of accessing main/critical functionality
> 3. Users may glance at it but may not click it. Like Racheet mentioned it in the comment, it may uplift the overall sales of that
>      product due to additional and/or persistent exposure.

[image]